# Golang build: get 'Syntax error: newline unexpected' when executing executable from specific path

Tags: go

My app is packaged as the following:

```
|-cmd/
|-cmd/application/ <- this contains the main.go and other files
|-internal/ <- contains internal dependencies
|-vendor/ <- contains third party libraries
```

And when running the following command from the root `/`:

```
go build cmd/application/*.go
```

It produces an executable that works fine. But when typing the following command from inside `/cmd/application`:

```
go build my_app_custom_name
```

I get the `Syntax error: newline unexpected` error, as if it wasn't a bash executable anymore.

Comment: Have you tried `go build .` (or `go build *.go`)?  The syntax `go build <name>` means "build the package at path `<name>` from GOROOT.  Also, your reference to a bash executable is confusing.  Were you trying to _run_ the executable you produced in the first command?  If so, `go build` isn't how you do it.  Also, syntax errors fired by `go build` note the file and line number they occur at.

Comment: `Syntax error: newline unexpected` is very likely a bash error. After which command does this message pop up?

Comment: Please read through [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html). Go build is meant to work on "packages", not a list of files.

Comment: I've tried using `go build .` and `go build *.go` from inside `cmd/application` and when trying to launch the executable I get the bash error `Syntax error: newline unexpected`

I'm still learning golang, trying to find a way to build go app and package them. Already read How to Write Go Code btw.
Thank you all btw2

Comment: All close votes require their motives--no need to ask for that in your question.

Comment: It is neither `go build .` nor `go build *.go`, it is either `go build` or `go build full/import/path/of/package/to/build` and add -v and -x flags to see whats going on.

Comment: Except that `go build .` and `go build *.go` both work perfectly fine, Volker.  `go build` is specifically designed to be able to take a file or list of files as an alternative to the recommended package syntax.

Comment: @Kaedys: except that's not the intended usage. "How to Write Go Code" makes no mention of that pattern, and even the help output for `go build` is only `usage: build [-o output] [-i] [build flags] [packages]`, as opposed to `go run` which is `usage: run [build flags] [-exec xprog] gofiles...`

Comment: Except it does mention it, literally two paragraphs later: `If the arguments to build are a list of .go files, build treats them as a list of source files specifying a single package.`

Comment: @Kaedys: fair point, I thought that was in a different doc. I still think the primary behavior is what we should focus on, rather than telling beginners that are already confused they can use the exception to the rule, except with caveats. If they start by using packages correctly, then there is far less confusion moving forward.

Comment: That's fair, and I've commented on other questions out here in the past that we _should_ focus on the _recommended_ style.  I just _do_ actually use the file name style fairly regularly personally, hence why I noted it (though part of that is that my workplace has this nasty habit of putting multiple mutually-uncompilable files with `main()` functions in the same dir, and just compiling them by file name >.>)

Answer (score 9):

With the help of the indication @Volker  after using the flags -v and -x I figured out that I was naming the package "myapp" and not "main" as it should be. Now it works just fine.

As said by @Kaedys and @JimB, it is preferable to use the standard form for building apps :

```
go build // Method one from inside directory with go files
go build full/import/path/of/package/to/build // second method
```

Note that this is the recommended way in [How to write Go code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Library)

The other way to build is using `go build .` and `go build *.go` in the directory where you go package is.